# What do I need to download and how to I upgrade my vmware in order to get VDP?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, vmware-vcenter

EDIT: I leave the question as is. Apparently I missed the part that it was only announced, and was sure it's released, and I can't find it on my.vmware.com

VDP [vmware data protection] was [recently launched](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/data-protection.html)

Assuming this is my Vcenter version

[image]

When I log in to my.vmware.com can anyone please assist on what do I need to download, and how to I upgrade it?

I always fear I am going to destroy everything :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not available for download yet and we don't deal with unreleased code on serverfault. Come back, or better yet read the documentation, once it's released rather than announced.

That said basically you just upgrade your VC and hosts to 5.1 and deploy the VDP .ovf like you did for VDR, the process is the same.

Comment: Thanks. Still, no where does it say that SF does or does not deal with unreleased code.

Comment: being a resource for systems engineers/administrators, one can hope that people will refrain from using alpha/beta software in production environments :P At least not as a rule.

Comment: @Saariko, that's a good point, it's something that is generally accepted but I'll see about getting it added to the FAQ, thanks.

Comment: See my edit: I mistakenly though that 5.1 was released. Didn't notice it was only announced.